# Deleting all the values in a table

Tags: ios, iphone, sqlite

In an iPhone application, is it possible to delete all the values in a table through sqlite? If so, what is the query for it? Please help me out.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming it uses standard SQL, that would simply be:

```
delete from MYTABLE
```

where `MYTABLE` is the name of the table you want to clear. I know with SQLite3 on the desktop you can also run a vacuum operation afterwards to compact the database. Whether that's available on the iPhone, I can't say, but you should investigate it since the `delete` doesn't necessarily free up any space.

Answer (score 0):

A quick `DELETE FROM tablename` should do it